# an object of the type cannot be applied to a property that expects the type system.windows.data.ivalueconverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a converter that highlight some keywords in a different colorsin a report. I didn't use IValueconverter because the keywords is hardcoded. However, I got the error in the xaml. How do I solve it:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <converter:HighlightKeywordsConverter x:Key="highlightKeywordsConverter" />
 </ResourceDictionary>
<local:AdvisoryReportView x:Name="_advisoryReportView" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          DataContext="{Binding AdvisoryViewModels, Converter={StaticResource highlightKeywordsConverter}}"/>
```

C#

```
 public class HighlightKeywordsConverter
{
    //public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    public object Convert(AdvisoryViewModelCollection input)
    {
        string returnText = string.Empty; // "Nothing Selected";
        string searchText = null;
        string[] keyWords = new string[]
            {
                "CLSD Closed",
                "BA NIL Braking action nil",
                "BA POOR Braking action poor",
            };


                   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (input.ToString().Contains(keyWords[i]))
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        searchText = String.Format("<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Blue\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        searchText = String.Format("<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Beige\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        searchText = String.Format("<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Azure\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                        break;


                } //end of switch
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    string replacePattern = @"(?![^<>]*>)(" + searchText + ")";

                    returnText = Regex.Replace(input.ToString(),
                                               replacePattern,
                                               searchText,
                                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
            } //end of if
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, just send back the original text, or an 
                // empty string if we did not get anything.
                returnText = input.ToString();
            }
        } //end of for
        return returnText;
    } //end of Convert
} //end of class
```

Comment: Converter needs to receive a resource that implements IValueConverter interface...the parameter value on Convert method will have the AdvisoryViewModelCollection that you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HighlightKeywordsConverter needs to implement `IValueConverter`.

Comment: How do I define the value for the hard coded texts that are needed for highlighting though?  These are not passed by the value parameter.

Comment: You have two possibilities. Or leave the hard coded values as you have, or define a StaticResource that binds to a list in your model with those keywords and pass it throught ConverterParameter.